# grunt: uglify css files with uglifyjs

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using grunt to uglify my static files (using grunt v0.4.0). I have configured it to uglify one file, but I can't figure out how to get it to do two files - [despite reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207983/how-to-specify-multiple-source-maps-in-uglify-grunt-task) and the [usage examples](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#usage-examples).

Here's what I have currently:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
    mangle: true
  },
  build: {
    src: 'dist/main.js',
    dest: 'dist/main.min.js'
  }
}
```

I'd like to uglify `dist/main.css` as well. How can I add it? I tried this, following the usage examples:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
    mangle: true
  },
  build: {
    files: {
      'dist/main.min.js': ['dist/main.js'],
      'dist/main.min.css': ['dist/main.css']
    }
  }
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
WARN: ERROR: Unexpected token: punc ({) [dist/main.css:7,41]
Warning: Uglification failed. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Seems like it's choking on the first `{` - why would that happen? It is valid CSS.

Comment: Uglify is for Javascript not CSS. Try using https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin for your CSS

Comment: @drzax Why not make this an answer? It seems like one.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Why the downvote? Obviously this is a stupid question, but that doesn't mean no-one else is going to have the same problem!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Uglify is for Javascript not CSS. Try using http://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin to minify CSS using Grunt.

Comment: Is it possible to emulate a separate 'dist' and 'dev' behavior like is done with uglifyjs? This way, the files are 'concatenated' but we can enable 'beautify' so that they are easy to debug - this works on uglifyjs, but I can't get it to work with cssmin, similar to this: uglify: {
   dist: {
    src: 'src/js/*.js',
    dest: 'js/script.min.js'
   },
   dev: {
    options: {
     beautify: true,
     mangle: false,
     compress: false,
     preserveComments: 'all'
    },

Answer (score 5):

Uglify is for Javascript only, but YUI Compressor can do both Javascript and CSS: [YUI Compressor](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-yui-compressor)

Answer (score 5):

There is a similar solution called **UglifyCSS** (https://github.com/fmarcia/UglifyCSS):

```
shell: uglifycss "source.css" > "output.min.css"
```

Where behaves much like **UglifyJS**.