# Compile, concat, and minify many source files during build process, with source maps

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to put together a Grunt task to build our JS assets as part of our build/deploy process. I'd characterize our needs as fairly standard, but serious (in that we need to support a real-world production app, not just a toy example).

We have a bunch of source files, some JavaScript, some CoffeeScript, in a bunch of separate files in a structured directory tree. We need to compile the CoffeeScript, and concatenate and minify all the code into several defined output files (i.e. `all.js` and `vendor.js`). And we need to end up with usable source maps to accompany this output that reflect the *original* source (the CS or JS files), preferably with embedded `sourcesContent`.

I'm having a surprisingly difficult time putting this together, and have yet to find an example of a Gruntfile that accomplishes all of these goals in a realistic build scenario. Has anyone accomplished this? It seems like almost any major Angular project that's building with Grunt would have a set of requirements that looks a lot like ours.

Right now I'm using `grunt-contrib-coffee`, `grunt-contrib-concat`, and `grunt-contrib-uglify`, and have something that's almost working but for all sorts of trouble with relative paths in the source maps. I've also run into problems with [uglify not handling multiple source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207983/how-to-specify-multiple-source-maps-in-uglify-grunt-task), and problems with each of those plugins having different capabilities when it comes to reading and generating source maps.